# Adding items from array into objects within another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects

I am currently looping through the data that I have, getting all values for a specific column and adding them to an array, then limiting it to only unique values.

I also have a `reportSections` array that needs to be dynamic based on how many items are currently in my `date_group` array. How can I loop through those arrays and add the values to the `id` and `name` objects within my `reportSections` array?

Ideally, I'm thinking there might contain some sort of for loop that can loop through the `reportSections` array and dynamically add the values inside the `date_group` and `record_group` arrays to the `id` and `name` objects, but not sure how that would work.

```
  var date_group = [];
  var record_date = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      date_group.push(data[i]['date group']);
      record_date.push(data[i]['record date']);
    }

    date_group = _.uniq(date_group);
    record_date = _.uniq(record_date);

  const reportSections = [
    {id: 'date_group1', name: 'record_date1'},
    {id: 'date_group2', name: 'record_date2'},
    {id: 'date_group3', name: 'record_date3'},
    {id: 'date_group4', name: 'record_date4'},
    {id: 'date_group5', name: 'record_date5'},
    {id: 'date_group6', name: 'record_date6'},
  ];
```

Comment: please add all data to the question and add a wanted result as well.

Comment: so reportSections will be initially empty?

Comment: Do you have the guarantee that you can pair the way you want? What if you have you 7 unique dates but 8 unique records?

Comment: The way the data is set up, the data will pair with each other. So if there are 7 unique records, there will be 7 unique dates.

Comment: @Supercool. yes, reportSections would be initially empty. What is showing currently in reportSections in my question is the ideal structure of it after it would loop through the values in the date_group and record_date arrays.

Comment: we can achieve that but there is kind of confusion in your making date group and record date unique..i feel something is wrong

Comment: @Supercool. the current data contains about 1,000 rows. There is a date group column that specifies which date group each row is in so we can group each section of the report by its date group. However, there are only 6 unique date groups within the 1,000 rows of data as of right now. So when I use the for loop and loop through everything, its pulling a list of about 1,000 date groups when there are only actually 6 unique ones that i need. Does that make sense?

Comment: ok regarding date group thats fine what about record date...record date is separate for each record in the table right?

Comment: @Supercool. the way the data has been set up, record date is actually set up just like date group, where there are only a few unique values.

Comment: what is the purpose of report sections array? and there will be problem when no of values inside unique date group array and record date array dont match

Comment: @Supercool. the reportSections array creates different sections within the report based on the `id` object. So in the report, there will be a section of data for each date group. Since the number of date groups will be dynamically changing, it cant be hardcoded like the array normally is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding making items unique im confused looking at your question but try this solution.

Use `set` for unique records

```js
let data = [{
    "date group": "C",
    "record date": "13 Mar 20"
  },
  {
    "date group": "B",
    "record date": "11 Mar 20"
  },
  {
    "date group": "A",
    "record date": "11 Mar 20"
  },
  {
    "date group": "B",
    "record date": "12 Mar 20"
  },
  {
    "date group": "C",
    "record date": "11 Mar 20"


  }
]
let reportSections = [];
let dataGroups = new Set();
let recordDates = new Set();
data.forEach(item => {
  dataGroups.add(item['date group']);
  recordDates.add(item['record date'])
})
for (const [index, value] of [...dataGroups].entries())
  reportSections.push({
    id: value,
    name: [...recordDates][index]
  })
console.log(reportSections);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works for me. Thank you very much for taking the time and for the help!